# cannot get visual studios 2019 to render properly using soil

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glfw, soil

The code rendered correctly before adding textures. I am able to use SOIL GLUT and eclipse just fine, its just with visual studios that nothing seems to work.

Here is the code:

```
#include <GLEW/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <SOIL2.h>
#include <iostream>

// GLM Mathematics
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>


using namespace std;

int width, height;
const double PI = 3.14159;
const float toRadians = PI / 180.0f;

// Declare Input Callback Function prototypes
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset);
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos);
void mouse_button_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mode);

// Declare View Matrix
glm::mat4 viewMatrix;

// Camera Field of View
GLfloat fov = 45.0f;

void initiateCamera();

// Define Camera Attributes
glm::vec3 cameraPosition = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f); // Move 3 units back in z towards screen
glm::vec3 target = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // What the camera points to
glm::vec3 cameraDirection = glm::normalize(cameraPosition - target); // direction z
glm::vec3 worldUp = glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glm::vec3 cameraRight = glm::normalize(glm::cross(worldUp, cameraDirection));// right vector x
glm::vec3 cameraUp = glm::normalize(glm::cross(cameraDirection, cameraRight)); // up vector y
glm::vec3 CameraFront = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f); // 1 unit away from lense



// Camera Transformation Prototype
void TransformCamera();

// Boolean array for keys and mouse buttons
bool keys[1024], mouseButtons[3];

// Input state booleans
bool isPanning = false, isOrbiting = false;

// Pitch and Yaw
GLfloat radius = 3.0f, rawYaw = 0.0f, rawPitch = 0.0f, degYaw, degPitch;

GLfloat deltaTime = 0.0f;
GLfloat lastFrame = 0.0f;
GLfloat lastX = 320, lastY = 240, xChange, yChange; // Center mouse cursor
bool firstMouseMove = true;


// Draw Primitive(s)
void draw()
{
    GLenum mode = GL_TRIANGLES;
    GLsizei indices = 6;
    glDrawElements(mode, indices, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
}



// Create and Compile Shaders
static GLuint CompileShader(const string& source, GLuint shaderType)
{
    // Create Shader object
    GLuint shaderID = glCreateShader(shaderType);
    const char* src = source.c_str();

    // Attach source code to Shader object
    glShaderSource(shaderID, 1, &src, nullptr);

    // Compile Shader
    glCompileShader(shaderID);

    // Return ID of Compiled shader
    return shaderID;

}

// Create Program Object
static GLuint CreateShaderProgram(const string& vertexShader, const string& fragmentShader)
{
    // Compile vertex shader
    GLuint vertexShaderComp = CompileShader(vertexShader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    // Compile fragment shader
    GLuint fragmentShaderComp = CompileShader(fragmentShader, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Create program object
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();

    // Attach vertex and fragment shaders to program object
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShaderComp);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShaderComp);

    // Link shaders to create executable
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    // Delete compiled vertex and fragment shaders
    glDeleteShader(vertexShaderComp);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderComp);

    // Return Shader Program
    return shaderProgram;

}


int main(void)
{
    width = 640; height = 480;

    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Main Window", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    // Set input callback functions
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback);
    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, mouse_button_callback);
    glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scroll_callback);

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Initialize GLEW
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        cout << "Error!" << endl;


    GLfloat vertices[] = {

        // Triangle 1
        -0.5, -0.5, 0.0, // index 0
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, // red
        0.0, 0.0, // UV (bl)

        -0.5, 0.5, 0.0, // index 1
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0, // green
        0.0, 1.0, // UV (br)

        0.5, -0.5, 0.0,  // index 2 
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0, // blue
        1.0, 0.0, // UV (tl)

        // Triangle 2   
        0.5, 0.5, 0.0,  // index 3  
        1.0, 0.0, 1.0, // purple
        1.0, 1.0 // UV (tr)
    };

    // Define element indices
    GLubyte indices[] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        1, 2, 3
    };

    // Plane Transforms
    glm::vec3 planePositions[] = {
        glm::vec3(0.0f,  0.0f,  0.5f),
        glm::vec3(0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f),
        glm::vec3(0.0f,  0.0f,  -0.5f),
        glm::vec3(-0.5f, 0.0f,  0.0f),
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.5f,  0.0f),
        glm::vec3(0.0f, -0.5f,  0.0f)
    };

    glm::float32 planeRotations[] = {
        0.0f, 90.0f, 180.0f, -90.0f, -90.f, 90.f
    };

    // Setup some OpenGL options
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Wireframe mode
    //glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

    GLuint cubeVBO, cubeEBO, cubeVAO, floorVBO, floorEBO, floorVAO;

    glGenBuffers(1, &cubeVBO); // Create VBO
    glGenBuffers(1, &cubeEBO); // Create EBO

    glGenBuffers(1, &floorVBO); // Create VBO
    glGenBuffers(1, &floorEBO); // Create EBO

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &cubeVAO); // Create VOA
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &floorVAO); // Create VOA

    glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);

    // VBO and EBO Placed in User-Defined VAO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVBO); // Select VBO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeEBO); // Select EBO


    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Load vertex attributes
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Load indices 

     // Specify attribute location and layout to GPU
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(6 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    glBindVertexArray(0); // Unbind VOA or close off (Must call VOA explicitly in loop)


    glBindVertexArray(floorVAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, floorVBO); // Select VBO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, floorEBO); // Select EBO

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Load vertex attributes
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Load indices 

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(6 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // Load texture maps
    int crateTexWidth, crateTexHeight, gridTexWidth, gridTexHeight;
    unsigned char* crateImage = SOIL_load_image("crate.png", &crateTexWidth, &crateTexHeight, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
    unsigned char* gridImage = SOIL_load_image("grid.png", &gridTexWidth, &gridTexHeight, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);

    // Generate Textures  
    GLuint crateTexture; // for texture ID
    glGenTextures(1, &crateTexture);// Generate texture id
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, crateTexture); // Activate texture
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, crateTexWidth, crateTexHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, crateImage); // Generate texture
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D); // Texture resolution managment
    SOIL_free_image_data(crateImage); // Free imge from memory
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); // Unbind or close texture object

    GLuint gridTexture;
    glGenTextures(1, &gridTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gridTexture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, gridTexWidth, gridTexHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, gridImage);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    SOIL_free_image_data(gridImage);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);


    // Vertex shader source code
    string vertexShaderSource =
        "#version 410 \n"
        "layout(location = 0) in vec3 vPosition;"
        "layout(location = 1) in vec3 aColor;"
        "layout(location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;"
        "out vec3 oColor;"
        "out vec2 oTexCoord;"
        "uniform mat4 model;"
        "uniform mat4 view;"
        "uniform mat4 projection;"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(vPosition.x, vPosition.y, vPosition.z, 1.0);"
        "oColor = aColor;"
        "oTexCoord = texCoord;"
        "}\n";

    // Fragment shader source code
    string fragmentShaderSource =
        "#version 410 \n"
        "in vec3 oColor;"
        "in vec2 oTexCoord;"
        "out vec4 fragColor;"
        "uniform sampler2D myTexture;"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "fragColor = texture(myTexture, oTexCoord);"
        "}\n";

    // Creating Shader Program
    GLuint shaderProgram = CreateShaderProgram(vertexShaderSource, fragmentShaderSource);


    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Set frame time
        GLfloat currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;

        // Resize window and graphics simultaneously
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Use Shader Program exe and select VAO before drawing 
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram); // Call Shader per-frame when updating attributes


        // Declare transformations (can be initialized outside loop)        
        glm::mat4 projectionMatrix;

        // Define LookAt Matrix
        viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(cameraPosition, target, worldUp);

        // Define projection matrix
        projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(fov, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        // Get matrix's uniform location and set matrix
        GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "model");
        GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view");
        GLint projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection");


        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(viewMatrix));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projectionMatrix));


        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, crateTexture); // Apply crate texture (Auto detected by Uniform Sampler)
        glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO); // User-defined VAO must be called before draw. 

        // Transform planes to form cube
        for (GLuint i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            glm::mat4 modelMatrix;
            modelMatrix = glm::translate(modelMatrix, planePositions[i]);
            modelMatrix = glm::rotate(modelMatrix, planeRotations[i] * toRadians, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
            if (i >= 4)
                modelMatrix = glm::rotate(modelMatrix, planeRotations[i] * toRadians, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
            glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelMatrix));
            // Draw primitive(s)
            draw();
        }

        // Unbind Shader exe and VOA after drawing per frame
        glBindVertexArray(0); //Incase different VAO wii be used after

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gridTexture); // Apply grid texture
        // Select and transform floor
        glBindVertexArray(floorVAO);
        glm::mat4 modelMatrix;
        modelMatrix = glm::translate(modelMatrix, glm::vec3(0.f, -.5f, 0.f));
        modelMatrix = glm::rotate(modelMatrix, 90.f * toRadians, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        modelMatrix = glm::scale(modelMatrix, glm::vec3(5.f, 5.f, 5.f));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelMatrix));
        draw();
        glBindVertexArray(0); //Incase different VAO will be used after



        glUseProgram(0); // Incase different shader will be used after

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();

        // Poll Camera Transformations
        TransformCamera();

    }

    //Clear GPU resources
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &cubeVAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &cubeVBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &cubeEBO);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &floorVAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &floorVBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &floorEBO);


    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// Define input functions
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
    // Display ASCII Key code
    //std::cout <<"ASCII: "<< key << std::endl; 

    // Close window
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);

    // Assign true to Element ASCII if key pressed
    if (action == GLFW_PRESS)
        keys[key] = true;
    else if (action == GLFW_RELEASE) // Assign false to Element ASCII if key released
        keys[key] = false;

}
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
{

    // Clamp FOV
    if (fov >= 1.0f && fov <= 55.0f)
        fov -= yoffset * 0.01;

    // Default FOV
    if (fov < 1.0f)
        fov = 1.0f;
    if (fov > 55.0f)
        fov = 55.0f;

}
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{

    if (firstMouseMove)
    {
        lastX = xpos;
        lastY = ypos;
        firstMouseMove = false;
    }
    // Calculate mouse offset (Easing effect)
    xChange = xpos - lastX;
    yChange = lastY - ypos; // Inverted cam

                            // Get current mouse (always starts at 0)
    lastX = xpos;
    lastY = ypos;


    if (isOrbiting)
    {
        // Update raw yaw and pitch with mouse movement
        rawYaw += xChange;
        rawPitch += yChange;

        // Conver yaw and pitch to degrees, and clamp pitch
        degYaw = glm::radians(rawYaw);
        degPitch = glm::clamp(glm::radians(rawPitch), -glm::pi<float>() / 2.f + .1f, glm::pi<float>() / 2.f - .1f);

        // Azimuth Altitude formula
        cameraPosition.x = target.x + radius * cosf(degPitch) * sinf(degYaw);
        cameraPosition.y = target.y + radius * sinf(degPitch);
        cameraPosition.z = target.z + radius * cosf(degPitch) * cosf(degYaw);
    }
}
void mouse_button_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mode)
{
    // Assign boolean state to element Button code
    if (action == GLFW_PRESS)
        mouseButtons[button] = true;
    else if (action == GLFW_RELEASE)
        mouseButtons[button] = false;
}



// Define TransformCamera function
void TransformCamera()
{

    // Orbit camera
    if (keys[GLFW_KEY_LEFT_ALT] && mouseButtons[GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT])
        isOrbiting = true;
    else
        isOrbiting = false;

    // Focus camera
    if (keys[GLFW_KEY_F])
        initiateCamera();
}

// Define 
void initiateCamera()
{   // Define Camera Attributes
    cameraPosition = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f); // Move 3 units back in z towards screen
    target = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // What the camera points to
    cameraDirection = glm::normalize(cameraPosition - cameraDirection); // direction z
    worldUp = glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    cameraRight = glm::normalize(glm::cross(worldUp, cameraDirection));// right vector x
    cameraUp = glm::normalize(glm::cross(cameraDirection, cameraRight)); // up vector y
    CameraFront = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f); // 1 unit away from lense
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you checking that those SOIL_load_image() calls return valid image pointers & image dimensions? Have you verified your program's working directory is what your relative paths are assuming it is?

Comment: Its my teachers source code,  it seems to be working for everyone else (its an online class but I havent heard anything about it not working on other systems) I am very new to opengl could you please elaborate about the image pointers. The relatives paths were orginally relatively linked but after it failed with relative linking I directly linked all of the libraries and header files and included SOIL in the include and in the additional directories with soil.lib

Comment: When I set it up in eclipse with mingw (for glfw3 ) and I received an entire list of errors about undefined references to soil functions when I loaded it the same way I did using glut             Here are some of them:                                                                                                        
b/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x8f): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'